# How do I get collisions to function when using mantaflow fluid simulations?

Tags: fluid-simulation, collision, mantaflow

I need help getting collisions to work in this fluid simulation. I tried increasing the resolution 256 in the domain settings. I tried increasing the subdivisions of the first collision object that comes into contact with the fluid. I checked to see if the normals for facing inward, which they were. I tried combining rigid body collisions with the fluid based collisions. I tried increasing and decreasing the size of the object and domain. None of these solutions have worked. Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Picture of Simulation]

[image: Domain Settings 2]

[image: Domain Settings 3]

[image: Domain Settings 4]

[image: Domain Settings 5]

[image: Object Settings 1]

[image: Object Settings 2]

[image: Collision Settings 1]

[image: Collision Settings]

[image]

Comment: The one thing you haven't shown is the settings for your collision object, which is called an effector in MantaFlow. Can you show screenshots of that?

Comment: if you could provide your blend file we could check it out...

Comment: @MartyFouts I just added the collision settings

Comment: @Chris I posted the Blend File

Comment: could you please check that file you uploaded? i got an error when i try to open it...and i never had such an error ever before....

Comment: @Chris what was the error? It worked when I redownloaded it.